# "No route matches [POST]" despite Resources in my Routes file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a Rails app, and I need a form to function in one of my views and submit data to a table without the use of a scaffold (like I usually do).

Now, the place where this comment form is going to appear is in one view within the `blog` folder. It will need to allow the user to put in their comment, save it to the table, and then return to the same page.

While this is a pretty commonplace error, I am confused because I am specifying two things that seem critical: creating resources in my routes file for the form, and second, using a create method in my controller.

In the **blog.html.erb**, this happens in this form:

```
<%= form_for :cements do |f| %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :post %><br>
                    <%= f.text_area :post, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <h5 id="username">Username</h5>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <%= f.hidden_field :slug, :id => "hiddenPicker"%>

    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-success-outline" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Then, in my controller, I have a create method that should redirect back to the original page, as I wanted.

**blogs_controller.rb**

```
class BlogsController < ActionController::Base

    def index
        @posts = Post.order('updated_at DESC').all
        @comments = Cement.all
    end

    def blog
        @posts = Post.where(slug: params[:id]).all
        @comments = Cement.all
    end 

    def create
        @cements= Cement.new(story_params)
        @cements.save
        redirect_to(:back)
    end

    private

    def story_params
        params.require(:cements).permit(:username, :post, :slug)
    end

end
```

Good news: the comment form renders in the view. Bad news: when I submit, I am getting this error: No route matches [POST] "/blog".

My expectation is this will be an issue with my Routes file; however, I have a `resources` method already in there:

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  resources :cements
  resources :blogs

The naming convention is the same as my controller file, so I am confused why this error is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: how did you initialized `:cements` ? and make sure you define the action blogs in your route too. `resources :blogs do get 'blog', on: :collection end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:cement` is not an object it is just a `symbol`, so how rails will determine where to `POST` form? If you inspect your form you will see form `action` as `/blog` (current page url).

You should either do

```
<%= form_for :cements, url: cements_path do |f| %>
```

or

```
<%= form_for Cement.new do |f| %>
```

Both of above will generate form action as `/cements`, which will submit to `CementsController` `create` action, But I see in your case you want to submit it to BlogsController so use the appropriate routes(blogs_path). You can use `url` in second version also.

Comment: Great answer, appreciate the background too.